# Check for event listener(vb) for an event raised in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

For a C# CollectionChanged event, how would one define a VB event handler?

For the C# code snippet, the expression `CollectionChanged != null` evaluates to false probably indicating the VB event handler has not being defined correctly or I might be missing very basic.

```
 public event CollectionChangeEventHandler CollectionChanged;
 protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(CollectionChangeAction action, Expression  element)
 {
     if (CollectionChanged != null) //always null
     {
         CollectionChangeEventArgs e = new CollectionChangeEventArgs(action, element);
         CollectionChanged(this, e);
     }
 }
 // Usage: OnCollectionChanged(CollectionChangeAction.Refresh, item);
```

The VB event handler is defined as below:

```
AddHandler Expression.ExpressionsCollection.CollectionChanged, AddressOf ExpressionsCollectionUpdated
```

Comment: Your code should work.  Are you adding a handler to the wrong instance?

Comment: If the VB code has the wrong definition it will show up as a type error.

Comment: @SLaks Yes - The event handler was added in the wrong constructor.